# Table rows not calculating on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with column totals and row totals.  I have it set up that when someone enters a number into the input fields it calculates them on keyup and on page load.  The columns are recalculating on page load just fine, but the rows are resetting back to zero.

```
// Calculate Sum Of Rows
$(function() {
    $('input').live('keyup', newSum);
    newSum();
});
function newSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    //iterate through each input and add to sum
    $(thisRow).find("input:not(.ignore):not(.description):not(.miles)").each(function() {
            val = parseFloat(this.value);
            sum += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;   
    });
    //change value of total
    $(thisRow).find(".sumtotalclaimed").html(sum);
}
```

Here's the code for the columns, which works perfectly (recalculates on page load):

```
// Calculate Sum Of Columns
$(function() {
    $('input.miles').live('keyup', calculateSum1);  
    calculateSum1();
} );
function calculateSum1() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("input.miles").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#summiles").html(sum);
}
```

I thought it would be as simple as putting newSum(); in the function, but that's not working.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `this` on page load.  So it can't find `thisRow`.  The offending line is `var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');`

The way I've done this in the past is to find the first input in question and trigger the event, thus calling the method with a fully inflated event.

For example, instead of calling `newSum();` directly, call  `$('input').first().trigger('keyup')` which will automatically call the `newSum` function.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/DTPZQ/3/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I tried this, to no avail: `$(function() {
  $('input').live('keyup', newSum);
  $('input').first().trigger('click');
 });`

Comment: Sorry I wrote the example based on my most common use cases -- clicks!  You want to do `.trigger('keyup')` not click.  Updating my post accordingly.

Comment: That's supposed to recalculate the row totals on page load?  I tried it and it doesn't work, but I guess I'm confused how 'keyup' would calculate row totals on page load.  I apologize if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I don't follow your question then.  I fixed your error, in that you can't called newSum directly because it uses `this` so you need to trigger/fake the event so that `this` is an element.  Notice that calculateSum1 iterates every element (.each) and sums things up.  newSum is a per-row event handler.  Do you want to trigger every row's event handler on load so each row's `.sumtotalclaimed` is calculated?  If so, then remove the `.first()` and let it trigger on every input.

Comment: Maybe I'm not putting your code in the right place then, because when I submit the form and postback or refresh the page, the row calculations reset back to zero, but the columns recalculate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DTPZQ/3/ Dunno what to tell you.  I did exactly what I was suggesting, and it worked just fine.  I faked two rows with real data, then the only thing I did to your JS was add `$('input').trigger('keyup');` and it started recalculating the rows.

Comment: man, I swear I did just that and it didn't work for me.  Either way, I copy and pasted what you put in and it worked!  Thanks for your help buddy!